# How to insert data from another table while column values equals in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres, suppose I have two tables.

Table A:

```
ID Gender
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Table B:

```
ID Gender    
1   F
2   M
3   F
```

How could I insert the gender values from Table B to Table A and get new table A like this:
Table A:

```
ID Gender
1  F
1  F
2  M
2  M
3  F
3  F
```

I tried commands like:

```
insert into a(gender) select gender from b 
where a.id=b.id;
```

and it gives me error info:

> there is an entry for table "a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: You haven't joined table b with table a likes select gender from b,a
where a.id=b.id; Also insert statement should contain values as the standard syntax; You syntax is not proper at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
UPDATE TABLE "A" Set "Gender" = "B"."Gender"
FROM "B"
WHERE "A"."ID" = "B"."ID";
```

Hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any `joins` ? (i.e. *inner* or *outer*)

```
SELECT a.ID, b.Gender    
FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b 
               ON b.ID = a.ID;
```

However, this would be considered as separated *result set* or you could do the *insert* operation

Answer (score 0):

Postgres throws and error on @Mabu Kloesen's answer. Should be just `update <table_name>`, not `update table <table_name>`.

Let's suppose that tables are named as "tableA" and "tableB", then the code could look like this:

```
UPDATE tableA set Gender = tableB.Gender
FROM tableB
WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32326529)